# Using Visual Studio 2022 breakpoints turn white while running and stop breaking during execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor

I'm using Blazor and Visual Studio 2022. Suddenly all VS breakpoints in the client (wasm) project turn white during execution and stop breaking execution when program runs. The breakpoints in the server project work fine. This started to happen after I renamed a procedure in the client project and renamed it back to the original name.

I have tried cleaning and recompiling project as well as exiting and reentering VS with no results.

From what I've read maybe a symbols file is not being loaded. If so, how can I force this to happen? Is there a setting to adjust?

Comment: This happens to me when a referenced project can't compile.

Comment: In the root folder of your project (wherever the SLN files are) should be a hidden `.vs` folder. Close Visual Studio and delete this folder, then relaunch. That solves 99% of my Visual Studio problems including Blazor-related.

Comment: Thanks Eto, but it didn't work. Following other suggestions I am investigating on trouble with https, but nothing yet.

Comment: Can you provide steps and minimal code sample to help us reproduce your problem? Will the problem occur when copying the code to a new project?

Comment: Appreciate your response, Minxin. I'll prepare a video to show you the problem.

Comment: Hi Mixin,I am attaching a video demonstrating the problem tracing code in the Blazor WASM front end of the application I am developing. https://1drv.ms/v/s!Asc3rS31b50fgc87oIFMAS0fIWyNVg?e=3GO3tR Please let me know when you receive this.  For additional information we can communicate via this chat

Comment: If the problem didn't occur before, consider rolling back  and checking what changed.

Comment: Tried running an older version of the project that used to stop at client side breakpoints, but now it won't stop at breakpoints in the client either.  I also uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio and didn't do the job either.  I'll now try installing an older version of Visual Studio and will report.

Comment: Uninstalled version 17.9.5 of Visual Studio and installed version 17.9.4. Rebuilt solution after deleting all obj and bin directories within the solution, but no results.  Left to try are installing solution in my home computer and developing with VS code, though really would prefer stay with Visual Studio.  Will let you know

Comment: Finally I got results. 1. Explanation first. I normally make zip files of the whole project periodically and unzipping these is how I have been getting at older versions. I

Comment: Got results. 1. NOTE: I normally back up by zipping project directory, and unzip to a new location to get version ready for testing. 2. Found that unzipping older version of code does not allow tracing client side code. 3. Installed earlier version of VS, same data => No results. 4. Downloaded project from github to my home computer => Able to trace client side code 5. Updated office computer with version from github => success  6. In summary: copying program to another computer and updating versions from github brought success. Don't know what did the trick. Thank you for your help Minxin Yu.